How does python's open() read mode and read binary mode deal with null bytes and f.seek?
I did 2 experiments

rb mode
r mode

with open("small_file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.seek(2)
    f.write("Content")

with open("small_file.txt", "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(f"START|{content}|END")

f.seek(2) during write is to insert some nullbytes (2 being arbitrary).
Output: START|b'\x00\x00Content'|END  (No surprise here)
If i change rb to r, i get START|Content|END.
What are the underlying concepts here to explain the behaviour of not reading (or reading but not printing?) null bytes, is it specified in any documentation?

Please ask only one question per question.

Null bytes have no printable representation so although they're read (mode="r") you can't see them if you naively try to print them
